# Jquery integrity can be generated or can it also be copied?

Tags: jquery, integrity

I am currently using the following link to use jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I copied this link from a website.
I know that a hash is generated from the code to see whether it has been manipulated or not.

The question I have is do I have to generate my own hash for my website or can I use the copied one because I would come up with the same hash anyway?

Comment: if it's the same code, you would end up with the same hash

Comment: But it just But it's all about the code I'm loading in, right? (in this case "jquery")

Comment: yeah, it's a SHA256 hash of the `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` file - the file won't load if the hash won't match - this is to avoid code injection, but .... let's be honest - everyone who would like to inject the code would do it by simply removing that attribute

Comment: If you copy the same jquery.js file and serve it from your site `<script src="mysite.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` then yes, you can use the same hash (or no hash at all).  You can't use a different hash.  The hash is based on the file, not where it's hosted.

Comment: Am I allowed to use the script from code.jquery.com?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Jquery integrity can be generate</title>
  </head>
 <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <span id="display"></span>
 </body>
</html>
```